# How to run Spark structured streaming using local JAR files

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I'm using one of the Docker images of EMR on EKS (emr-6.5.0:20211119) and investigating how to work on Kafka with Spark Structured Programming (pyspark). As per the [integration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying), I run a Python script as following.

```sh
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --master local \
  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 \
  <myscript>.py
```

It download the package from Maven central and I see some JAR files are downloaded into `~/.ivy2/jars`.

```sh
com.github.luben_zstd-jni-1.4.8-1.jar       org.apache.spark_spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar             org.slf4j_slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
org.apache.commons_commons-pool2-2.6.2.jar  org.apache.spark_spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar  org.spark-project.spark_unused-1.0.0.jar
org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar    org.lz4_lz4-java-1.7.1.jar                                       org.xerial.snappy_snappy-java-1.1.8.2.jar
```

However I find the main JAR file is already download into `$SPARK_HOME/external/lib` and I wonder how to make use of it instead of downloading it.

```sh
spark-avro_2.12-3.1.2-amzn-1.jar          spark-ganglia-lgpl.jar                      spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12-3.1.2-amzn-1.jar   spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly.jar
spark-avro.jar                            **spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2-amzn-1.jar  spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly.jar                     spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2-amzn-1.jar
spark-ganglia-lgpl_2.12-3.1.2-amzn-1.jar  **spark-sql-kafka-0-10.jar                    spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.12-3.1.2-amzn-1.jar  spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10.jar
```

**UPDATE 2022-03-09**

I tried after updating `spark-defaults.conf` as shown below - added the external lib folder.

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath      /usr/lib/spark/external/lib/*:...
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath    ...
spark.executor.extraClassPath    /usr/lib/spark/external/lib/*:...
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath  ...
```

I can run without `--packages` but it fails with the following error.

```
22/03/09 05:37:25 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPoolConfig
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer$.<init>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:623)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer$.<clinit>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchPartitionReader.<init>(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchReaderFactory$.createReader(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD.compute(DataSourceRDD.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPoolConfig
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 33 more
```

It doesn't help although I tried with adding `--packages org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.6.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot submit an app only with the JAR files in `$SPARK_HOME/external/lib` due to an error. The details of the error are updated to the question. Instead I ended up pre-downloading the package JAR files and using those.

I first ran with the following command. Here `foo.py` is an empty file and it'll download the package JAR files into `/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars`.

```sh
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --master local \
  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 \
  foo.py
```

Then I updated `spark-defaults.conf` as following.

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath      /home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/*:...
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath    ...
spark.executor.extraClassPath    /home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/*:...
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath  ...
```

After that, I ran the submit command without `--packages` and it worked without an error.

```sh
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --master local \
  <myscript>.py
```

This approach is likely to be useful when it takes long to download package JAR files as they can be pre-downloaded. Note EMR on EKS supports using a custom image from ECR.

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't use `--master local` in EMR. That being said, all the executors need to download the same files unless you use something like rsync or Ansible to distribute them internally to your VPC (or package in a container, like you say, but you still need the Docker daemon to download those images)

Comment: This is for local development. For production, it'll be deployed to EKS. EMR on EKS supports a custom image from ECR (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/docker-custom-images.html). I can build an image with those JAR files included. It would be beneficial if it takes long to download all the JAR files.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `--jars` to refer to local filesystem in-place of `--packages`

Comment: Simply adding `--jars $SPARK_HOME/external/lib/spark-sql-kafka-0-10.jar` doesn't seem to work as it requires multiple JAR files. Adding every JAR file doesn't seem to be practical.

Comment: Well, this is the answer you're looking for. Nothing in the external folder is used, by default. Besides, you only need kafka-clients JAR here, and you'd still need to include that if you moved the sql-kafka jar into Spark's main lib folder on all executors

Comment: No, it's not the answer I'm looking for. What I need is how to work on Spark structured streaming without downloading an external package. If you think your answer is sufficient, please give me full details.

Comment: @Jae That's not possible. Spark by itself doesn't include Kafka libraries. They'd have to be downloaded at some point. If they are available on disk by EMR, then fine, but you still need to modify the execution command to reference those files

Comment: See my update. There should be a reason that the JAR files are downloaded already. I'm looking for how to make use of those. For example, if I want to use Hudi, I can use an existing one.